# 1950's or 1960's Short Science Fiction Story About a Body Swapping Machine and a Man's Search to Find his Former Body

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a 1950's or 1960's futuristic short story about a man who had changed bodies with another.  He was on a quest to find his former body. I believe the two parties had to agree with the switch.  After a long search he found the man inhabiting his body and made the switch.  I remember the technician who operated the switching machine telling the man, after the switch, that it would take time to feel comfortable in his body again.

Comment: Did it involve him finding out that his most recent switch was into a body that the other person didn't own, meaning he had a limited amount of time to find the scammer before he was evicted?

Comment: Robert Sheckley wrote a whole novel about this called [*MindSwap* (1966)](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9685)

Comment: FuzzyBoots - I cannot remember the limited time aspect, but that could have part of it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ross Presser - I believe MindSwap may be the one I am looking for.  I read quite a number of reviews online and now I remember there was a criminal involved. I do not remember the detective or comedy part of it but is has been 50 years. I appreciate your answer and FuzzyBoots's, too.

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate. Please don't think that this means this is a bad question. It's just one that's been answered before, and we like to tie those together in the system. You can still accrue votes even with it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's longer than a short story, but might you be thinking of Robert Sheckley's *[Mindswap](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/196262.Mindswap)*?

> In the future, interstellar travel to alien worlds will be too expensive for most ordinary people. It certainly is for Marvin, a college student who wants to take a really good vacation. And so he signs up for what he can afford, a mindswap, in which your consciousness is swapped into the body of an alien lifeform. But Marvin is unlucky, and finds himself in the body of an interstellar criminal, a body that he has to vacate fast. But that criminal consciousness has stolen Marvin's earthly body, and Marvin has to find a body on the black market.
>
> Travel from world to world with Marvin, each one crazier than the last, as he keeps finding far from ideal bodies in awful situations, just to stay alive.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is it.

Comment: *Mindswap* was first published as a novella in *Galaxy* which might explain the OP remembering it as a short story. On the other hand, the ending in the OP's description is not like anything in *Mindswap*.

Comment: @Roy You can read *Mindswap* here https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n05_1965-06/page/n7/mode/2up

Answer (score 1):

Another story that involves a voluntary body-swap that the protagonist seeks to reverse is "[New Bodies for Old](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77663)" (1950) by Jack Vance.  (It was reprinted as "[Chateau d'If](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?96383)" in Vance's collection *The Narrow Land*.)

Roland Mario and his compatriots are young, underemployed and bored in a moderately futuristic city.  In turn they each try answering an advertisement for adventure, but never return.  Roland takes his turn, and finds himself transferred into the body of an old, fat industrialist who has looted his companies for the money to buy a new body (Roland's).

The rest of the story follows Roland's campaign to force the return of his original body.

The story was first published in [*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, August 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61686) and can be read [at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v36n03_1950-08/page/n45/mode/2up).

Comment: Yes, this story is along the same lines.  I think the one I am looking for is MindSwap, but if it is not, I'll check out your suggestion.